Size doubling amoeba
Note: Here time is assumed to be discrete and indexed by the naturals $\mathbb N$.
A curious species of amoeba undergoes the following evolution rule - at each time step, with probability $0 < p < 1$ it splits into two copies of itself of size $\varepsilon S$, where $S$ is the original size of the amoeba, and $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ is a fixed number. With probability $q = 1-p$, it doubles in size instead.
Start with one amoeba of size $1$. Denoting by $S^{\max}_t$ the size of the largest amoeba at time $t$, for what values of the parameters $\varepsilon, p$ do we have
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} S^{\max}_t = \infty$$
almost surely?

I thought for a second there that the post was about tropical geometry :-)

@M.G. Unfortunately it is about fictional amoeba, not mathematical amoeba :P

Great question. +1

Does $S$ denote the starting size of the amoeba (which you said is $1$) or the size right before splitting?

Also, you said "it" after talking about the species, which I think you didn't mean to do. Is each amoeba evolving according to the rule (simultaneously)?

@mathworker21 It is the size before splitting. And yes, each amoeba evolves according to the same rule.

If $\epsilon > 2(\frac{1}{2})^{({1}/{p})}$, then $\lim_{t\in \infty} S_t^{\mbox{max}}=\infty$ almost surely.  This follows from the strong law of large numbers.  If you track the size of the original amoeba and pick one copy when it splits, then the expected size is $(\epsilon^p 2^q)^{n} \to \infty$, if $\epsilon^p 2^q >1$.  By the strong law (or ergodic theorem), the size of this amoeba goes to infinity almost surely.  This doesn't take into account that there might be on the order of $2^{pn}$ amoebas at stage $n$, so there is likely a better bound.  Probably stating the obvious here.

This question can be cast in the language of branching random walks: at each (discrete) time, a particle splits with probability $p$ and each of the children moves $\log \epsilon$; if it did not split, it moves $\log 2$. You are asking about the largest particle moving to infinity, i.e. the velocity being positive (essentially). This fits the model described e.g. in Zhan Shi's St Flour lecture notes, specifically Theorem 2.3 there. Let $\psi(t)= \log (2p \epsilon^t+q 2^t)$,
then $v=\inf \psi(t)/t$, and you are asking whether $v>0$ or not. This is the sought after criterion.
The link to Shi's lecture notes is: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-25372-5

The language is more versatile than expected… thanks!
